# How to properly use payment intent, i keep getting error invalid paymentintent status

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am trying to implement the payment intent api and i kept getting the invalid payment intent status, i saw an answer on stack-overflow but it doesn't help, 
i don't know if its a bad server side or client side implementation, as i am still new to this

I have tried changing the requires_action to requires_source_action, under the charges but nothing help, tried modifying the html, but i don't know what is wrong.

in charge, i have

```php
<?php
  # vendor using composer
  require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(getenv('sk_test_HERE'));

  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  # retrieve json from POST body
  $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
  //$amount=$POST['amount'];
//---------------- changed the intent from null;
  $intent = null;
  try {
    if (isset($json_obj->payment_method_id)) {
      # Create the PaymentIntent
      $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
        'payment_method' => $json_obj->payment_method_id,
        'amount' => 1000,
        'currency' => 'eur',
        'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
        'confirm' => true,
      ]);
    }
    if (isset($json_obj->payment_intent_id)) {
      $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve(
        $json_obj->payment_intent_id
      );
      $intent->confirm();
    }
    generatePaymentResponse($intent);
  } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
    # Display error on client
    echo json_encode([
      'error' => $e->getMessage()
    ]);
  }
//--------------------updated from requires action to requires source action
  function generatePaymentResponse($intent) {
    # Note that if your API version is before 2019-02-11, 'requires_action'
    # appears as 'requires_source_action'.
    if ($intent->status == 'requires_source_action' &&
        $intent->next_action->type == 'use_stripe_sdk') {
      # Tell the client to handle the action
      echo json_encode([
        'requires_action' => true,
        'payment_intent_client_secret' => $intent->client_secret
      ]);
    } else if ($intent->status == 'succeeded') {
      # The payment didn’t need any additional actions and completed!
      # Handle post-payment fulfillment
      echo json_encode([
        "success" => true
      ]);
    } else {
      # Invalid status
      http_response_code(500);
      echo json_encode(['error' => 'Invalid PaymentIntent status']);
    }
  }
?>
```

in the JavaScript file i have

```js
// Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_HERE');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
//                                     added an extra s for form control
card.mount('#card-elements');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});

// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
```

and this to collect the details, forgive me if you see any amateurish thing

```php
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="my-4 text-center">Service Payments</h2>

    <form action="./charge.php" method="post" id="payment-form">
        <div class="form-row">
         <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control mb-3 StripeElement StripeElement--empty" placeholder="First Name" required>
         <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control mb-3 StripeElement StripeElement--empty" placeholder="Last Name" required>
         <!-- <label for="t2">What's your e-mail?</label> -->
         <input type="email" name="email" id="t2" class="form-control mb-3 StripeElement StripeElement--empty" placeholder="Email Address" required>

         <input type="amount" name="amount" class="form-control mb-3 StripeElement StripeElement--empty" placeholder="1000 translates to 10.00" required>
         <!-- changed card element to elements with an s, form control is another possible option -->
         <input id="cardholder-name" type="text">
            <div id="card-elements" class="form-control">
            <!-- /  a Stripe Element will be inserted here. / -->
            </div>
            <!-- Used to display form errors -->
             <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
        <button  id="card-button" data-secret="<?= $intent->client_secret ?>">Submit Payment</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

i keep getting the error: invalid payment intent status

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might be working off older docs. You are getting "invalid payment intent status" because your code is looking for the status `requires_source_action`, which doesn't exist: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/intents#intent-statuses

The actual status is probably `requires_confirmation`, in which case you'll have to confirm the PaymentIntent on your server. Then depending on the status you either get the `requires_action` status or `succeeded`. Which one you get depends on whether the card in question requires 3DS or not.

Because your PaymentIntent is using the manual confirmation flow, it means you have to do several round trips between front and backend before a payment is actually completed. I recommend looking into using automatic confirmation instead. That way you have only 2 steps:

1. Create PaymentIntent on the server, pass the client secret ID to the frontend
2. Collect payment details with Elements like you are now, use the client secret from step 1 and Stripe.js' `handleCardPayment` to complete the payment

More info on that flow here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/quickstart#automatic-confirmation-flow

Unless you have a good reason to use manual confirmation, I'd stick with automatic.

Comment: when i use this ```php ?php
    $intent = # ... Fetch or create the PaymentIntent;
?>``` according to the docs, i get an error, and it is the same exact error, or is my html wrong, i have also changed the code of charge.php to the one on the stripe link, what is supposed to be in this intent, (a string, code ), please help